# filtering a rich:datatable with a rich:datascroller on richfaces 4

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am using richfaces 4, and i have a rich:datatable with a rich:datascroller and a column with a filter following the examples at the richfaces 4 showcase, but here's the thing,  once i filter the table and the datascroller updates(ie. if at first the datascrolloer has 10 pages and after the filter have 2 pages) if I click on the next page or any of the boundary controls it suppose to go to the next page of the filtered table but instead the table resets to its original state(with out the filter expression)

here is my code:

```
        <rich:dataTable id="mytbl" value="#{MyBean.mylist}" rows="10" 
                        var="emp" 
                        reRender="ds"
                        iterationStatusVar="it">            
            <f:facet name="noData">
                no data found
            </f:facet>
            <rich:column filterValue="#{MyBean.id_filter}"                           
                         filterExpression="#{fn:containsIgnoreCase(emp.id,MyBean.id_filter)}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:outputText value="id"/>                              
                        <h:inputText value="#{MyBean.id_filter}">
                            <a4j:ajax event="change" render="mytbl" execute="@this"
                                      onbegin="#{rich:component('wait_popup')}.show()"
                                      oncomplete="#{rich:component('wait_popup')}.hide()"/>
                        </h:inputText>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{emp.id}"/>
            </rich:column>

            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="value" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{emp.value}">
                    <f:convertNumber pattern="$#,###.00"/>
                </h:outputText>
            </rich:column>

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <rich:dataScroller maxPages="10" id="ds" render="@this" />
            </f:facet>

        </rich:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `MyBean` was not view scoped.